# Get lead assignment to ignore business name prefix

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

Essentially, we have business records coming in with company names, but we'd like the lead assignment rules to ignore prefixes such as "The" or "A", etc. Formula fields have been tried, but it seems the assignment fires before the formula calculation.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you assigning based on the results of the formula, or using a workflow rule?

Comment: Are you assigning the Lead based on Company name?

Comment: lead assignment rules can exploit formula fields as they are always calculated on demand. You should expose some sample lead assignment rules by using [edit] on your question

Answer (score 0):

You could use **before trigger** on Lead object, and replace whatever **prefix** is to be ignored. As per the salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), before trigger fire before assignment rules, so you should be good.

> **Sample Code**

```
trigger LeadTrg on Lead (before Insert) {
   for (Lead ld: trigger.new)
   {
       if (ld.Company.contains(<ignored string>)
            ld.Company = ld.Company.replace(<ignored string>, '');
   }
}
```

*Above code is create on-the-fly and not tested.*